# Solving using function in c

Tags: c

Problem is:**Write a function that returns the average value of the elements in the array.**
This is a solved problem, however **I need to solve it via function**, and not sure how to do it..Can anyone help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[20], num, i;     //array declaration
    double avg = 0, sum = 0; //variable declaration
    printf("Enter the numbers of average: ");
    scanf("%d", &num); //get inpur from user to numberof elements
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    { //loop for get input numbers
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i]; //loop for calculating sum
        avg = sum / num;    //calculate average
    }
    printf("Average of entered numbers are: %f", avg);
    getch(); //display result on the screen
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass the array and `num` as function arguments. The function calculates the average and returns it.

Comment: BTW, array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: But how to do it..can you edit my code or be more specific..i am new to this pplease help

Comment: The whole point of the assignment is for you to figure it out. Read a tutorial on functions.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this should help:

```
double calc_average(const int *array, size_t num_elements)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return (sum / num_elements);
}
```

with this prototype:

```
double calc_average(const int *array, size_t num_elements);
```

which you can call with:

```
avg = calc_average(arr, num);
```

but you'll need to fix your input loop in main() to start at 0:

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

and also in main() you should make sure you don't overrun the bounds of your array:

```
if(num > 20)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: too many numbers\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This is simple code.  Hopefully, I didn't make any simple mistakes.

Comment: i am making mistake somewhere.. https://pastebin.com/fPWSDPkG